# Tuple, List Python operations

Tags: python, list, date, time, tuples

```
def subtract_months(input_list):
    output_list = []
    
    #TODO: implement your code here
    new_list = [item for sublist in input_list for item in sublist]
    #print(flat_list)
        
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        if new_list[i][2] > new_list[i][1]:
            new_list[i][2] = new_list[i][1] - new_list[i][2]
      
    
input_list = [[(2000,1,14),(2020,5,3)]]
subtract_months(input_list)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-26dd75c8bd92> in <module>
     19 
     20 input_list = [[(2000,1,14),(2020,5,3)]]
---> 21 subtract_months(input_list)

<ipython-input-178-26dd75c8bd92> in subtract_months(input_list)
      9         print(i)
     10         if new_list[i][2] > new_list[i][1]:
---> 11             new_list[i][2] = new_list[i][1] - new_list[i][2]
     12 
     13 

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I am aware that tuples are immutable and hence, I converted them into a list but I get the same error of 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.
I want to update the values in the element itself.
For example: (2000,1,14) ->> (2000,12,-13).
I am performing the change in years and months. In the above example, 2000 is a year and 1 is the month and I want to subtract the  14 from 1 and update year and month accordingly.
NOTE: I don't want to use datetime.timedelta().

Thank you

Comment: Can you give more examples? Shouldn't the year change from 2000 to 1999 in your example?

Comment: Hint: After creating "new_list" execute "print(repr(new_list))" to see what you created.

Comment: @angelogro Yes the year should also change hence, I wrote year and month should change accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelButscher [(2000, 1, 14), (2020, 5, 3)]. This is the output for print(repr(new_list)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but the mistake is in line.

```
new_list = [item for sublist in input_list for item in sublist]
```

Try out the below code it should work if you can post your requirement more clearly it would be easier to understand and answer.

```
def subtract_months(input_list):
    output_list = []
    
    #TODO: implement your code here
    new_list = [list(item) for sublist in input_list for item in sublist]
    print(new_list)
    
        
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        if new_list[i][2] > new_list[i][1]:
            new_list[i][2] = new_list[i][1] - new_list[i][2]
    
    return new_list
      
    
input_list = [[(2000,1,14),(2020,5,3)]]
print(subtract_months(input_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
input_list = [[(2000,1,14),(2020,5,3)]]
```

to

```
input_list = [[[2000,1,14],[2020,5,3]]]
```

Tuples are immutable in Python. You can add elements to it but can't modify the contents inside themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do assignment with tuples, their immutable, you only can with lists, so you can change this line:

```
input_list = [[(2000,1,14),(2020,5,3)]]
```

To:

```
input_list = [[[2000,1,14],[2020,5,3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_list` is a list of tuples. `new_list[i][2] = ...` assigns to an item of a tuple [which is not allowed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples). Hence the error message.

To fix your code either use lists (see the answer of U11-Forward) or construct new tuples instead of trying to manipulate them.